# Can I have instances of a Component Factory that references different target services?

Tags: osgi, declarative-services

I have created 3 different components: Client, Executor and Methodology.

I can have multiple Client instances that references its own Executor instance. So I turned Executor as a DS factory component.

Executor can execute the Client request following one or more methodologies. so it references (1..n) Methodology services dynamically.

So far, so good. My problem is that I need to narrow the methodologies used by Executor component per client wish.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you create the component factory instances, you can supply different target properties to each instance. The target properties can be used to select referenced services.